# How do I hold in a key from the start of a loop, until it finishes in AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I Have a loop I am trying to get to work properly, so space is held throughout the entire looping period, and it doesnt have to be pressed within the loop to be activated.

I tried moving the space function outside of the loop, and release it after, but then it doesnt recognize the action at all.

```
toggle = 0
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 20

!Z::
Toggle := !Toggle
While Toggle{

Loop, X
{       
Send {Space down}
MouseMove, %X1%, %Y1%, 3,
MouseClick, L
Sleep Y
MouseMove, %X2%, %Y2%, 3
Sleep Y
MouseClick, L
Send {Space up}}
If !Toggle
Break
}
return
```

The result I want to happen is that for as long as that loop is running, spacebar is pressed down, from before the loop starts, and is released after the loop ends.

Comment: One thing to note from the help file, "When a key is held down via the [send command], it does not begin auto-repeating like it would if you were physically holding it down (this is because auto-repeat is a driver/hardware feature)." What behavior are you expecting with holding down the space key? What application/game is it used for?

Comment: I was expecting what you were describing, but if its not possible I have to try to solve it in another manner. Or does SendInput, SendRaw or another function mimic this? I tried adding a "While Loop" command to the sequence, that told it to {Space down}, but that didnt work either.

It's used for a program that's running in OpenGL.